# How to check whether file name contains a specific character with Pathlib

Tags: python, pathlib

Since it looks like Pathlib is the future, I'm trying to refactor some of my code to change from from previous use of os to Pathlib. I'm stuck with the following problem. Since I work with a Mac, sometimes the folders contain hidden files preceded by a period (.DS_Store or names from deleted files preceded by ._). That gets me into a lot of problems when I loop through files in a directory that have certain extension. To avoid this problem using os.walk, I do the following:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(DIR_NAME):

    # iterate all files
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(ext):
            if file.startswith("."):
                 continue
            do something with the file
```

I know we have the .stem and .suffix method to manipulate file names with Pathlib, but I don't see how they can help with this problem. The .startswith seems more intuitive but alas it does not seem to be available in Pathlib. So, the question is, how would one go about doing this in Pathlib?

Comment: Assuming `p` is a `pathlib.Path` variable, aren't you just asking `if p.name.startswith('.')`?

Comment: @larsks. Thank you. I'm so embarrassed I didn't look into the .name method. At the time the loop starts, the variable 'file' contains the whole path to the file (i.e. the_path_to_DIR_NAME/file.ext). Then when I do "if file.startswith(".") it fails. Of course, I need "if file.name.startswith('.')", and then everything works out. If you write your comment as an answer I'll be happy to check the question as answered. Otherwise I feel like deleting the question altogether because now I feel a little embarrassed for not having looked at the obvious solution and concentrate on .stem and .suffix.